# Is PESDK compatible with React 16.2?

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I am using React 16.2 and am running into issues when integrating PESDK

```
ERROR in ./~/photoeditorsdk/js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.Controls.Adjustments.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'photoeditorsdk/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.Core'
```

When pretty much following the example from the [demo repo](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-react-demo)

I also tried to clone the demo repo, and update it to React 16.2 and the latest PESDK version (4.3.0) and got the same issue

Is this compatible with React 16.2, and if not, do you have plans to support this in the near future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is compatible with React 16.2. 
The error you encounter is fixed in v4.3.1 that we released today.
Also take a look at our react demo integration athttps://github.com/imgly/pesdk-react-demo